# no result appear in my activity page

Tags: php, android, xml, android-activity

my problem is i can't see my data in my activity page but i can see it in log cat

> 11-01 03:14:25.295: D/All Products:(11015): {"success":1,"scb":[{"id":"14","title":"test1"},{"id":"15","title":"title"},{"id":"16","title":"title"},{"id":"17","title":"we"},

and my php files are fine i i know that because i test them.

```
    package com.example.studentcookbook;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//import com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity;
//import com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity;
//import com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity;
//import com.example.androidhive.R;
//import com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity.LoadAllProducts;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GetAllRecipesActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

        // url to get all products list
        private static String url_all_products = "http://studentcookbook.comoj.com/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_SCB_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";

        // products JSONArray
        JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_all_recipes);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.GetAllscbid)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditRecipeActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_SCB_ID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }//end onCreate method

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetAllRecipesActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_SCB_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_SCB_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_TITLE, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddRecipeActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(GetAllRecipesActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_recipe, new String[] { TAG_SCB_ID,TAG_TITLE},
                            new int[] { R.id.GetAllscbid, R.id.GetAllTitle });
                    // updating listview
                    Toast.makeText(GetAllRecipesActivity.this, "onPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }

}//end GetAllRecipesActivity class
```

these two are my xml files 
**list_recipe.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
           android:id="@+id/GetAllscbid"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:visibility="gone" />
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/GetAllTitle"
 android:layout_width="269dp"
 android:layout_height="34dp" />
```

this the other one ***activity_get_all_recipes.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like that you are working on something to do with recipes.

I think you should change the table name to your own DB table name:

```
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
```